# Inserting two list of variables into a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, shuffle

I currently have two lists of Variables. The first list is just the basic alphabet (I've named it the alpha list) and the second list is a shuffled version of that alphabet (I've named it the beta list). I would like to insert the Alpha list in a set of keys in a dictionary and the Beta list as a set of the values.

So far previous attempts on what I could find did not work for this situation

```py
import random

incoding_cipher= {} #creating empty dictionaries 

decoding_cipher= {}

alpha=['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']

beta= alpha[:]
random.shuffle(beta)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[zip](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#zip) is what you need. Try

```
dict(zip(alpha, beta))
```

Comment: thanks exactly what i needed

Comment: my pleasure @Cazards